# How can I pass a string from one Unit test to another in XCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I have two unit tests, testUserRegistration and testEmailConfirmation. The registration test runs first, I create a unique email to register with a random int, such as autoTest1234@test.com or autoTest4928@test.com. In the next test, testEmailConfirmation, I need to use that same username that I created in a previous test. How can I send it from one test method to another?

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you should think about unit tests.

First of all, you should not make assessments regarding test order: your tests are likely going to run in a random order, Xcode decides, not you. Your tests should be independent from each other, and you should be able to run them in any order. In Xcode 10, we'll have test parallelization and you really don't want them to be dependent one from each other. Finally this randomization is good to make sure your test is not working just because of a side effect.

Basically, you want two tests.

The first one looks like that:

```
func testUserRegistration() {
  // Given [an email address / username]
  // When [you run the registration flow]
  // Then [you assert that it worked]
}
```

Now that this test passes, you can consider that your user registration works and should not test it again. No need. This is why it's called "unit test", because you test "units".

Now in your second test, the unit you're testing is the "confirmation" part:

```
func testEmailConfirmation() {
  // Given [new email/username, you can call the registration method with this new email here]
  // When [you apply your confirmation flow]
  // Then [you assert that the confirmation is working]
}
```

you can call the user registration function (not the test, the real function) configured with another random email, and do the asserts based on this email.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by subclassing `XCTestCase`.

During setup if you block the thread while you network using semaphores and then unlbock the thread when you're done with your networking event.

You can also add variables to the subclass so you can have ready access to the variables in all of your tests.

For objective C you will have to split the files in .h and .m in order to be able to subclass your new integration test class.

An example **Objective-C** Implementation:

**IntegrationTest.h**

#import

```
@interface IntegrationTest : XCTestCase

// Add properties here you want your test cases to inherit.
// Added a user property as an example.
@property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) User *user;     

@end
```

**IntegrationTest.m**

```c
@implementation IntegrationTest 

-(void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    __weak IntegrationTest *wSelf = self;

    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [User registerUserWithEmail:@"SomeRandomEmail" completion:^(User *user, NSError * error) {
         wSelf.user = user;
         dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

}

-(void)tearDown {
    [super tearDown];

    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

     // Do any networking related to tearing down such as deleting the user you just created
    [self.user deleteWithCompletion:^(NSError *error) { 
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
     }];

     dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

 }
```

An example **Swift** implementation is below:

```swift
class IntegrationTest: XCTestCase {

     user: User?

     override func setUp() {
        super.setup()

        // Use a semaphore to block 
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        weak var wSelf = self

        registerUser(email: "SomeRandomEmail" ,completion: { (user, error) in 
           // Signal the semaphore for the tests to start running again
           // Do additional work, set variables, etc. here
           wSelf?.user = user
           semaphore.signal()
        })

        if semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(10)) == .timedOut {
           // If something goes wrong in the networking handle it here
           print("Networking failed")
        }    

     }

     override func tearDown() {

         let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

         if let nonNilUser = user {
            // Delete the user or do additional networking for the teardown in the same manner
            user.delete(completion: { (error) in 
                // Do additional tear down work here
                semaphore.signal()
            }
         } else {
            semaphore.signal()
         }            

     }        

}
```

All you need to do now is subclass the IntegrationTest class and call `super.setUp()` and `super.tearDown()` in *Swift* or `[super setUp]` and `[super tearDown]` if in *Objective-C*.

I have used this structure for over two years for Integration tests which require networking and authentication with good success.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not doing unit testing, but rather integration testing, or E2E testing (I have a hunch the other end is somewhere on a remote server). That's not a bad thing, but let's get the terminology straight :). Note that E2E tests can lead to false negatives for a fair amount of conditions, like temporary network unreachability, so they are not as robust as unit tests.

Making abstraction of the above, you could override the class `setUp`, and store the randomly generated email there:

```
@interface MyTestCase()
@property (class) NSString *email;
@property (class) NSString *password;
@end

@implementation MyTestCase

+ (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    self.email = [self someRandomEmailGenerator];
    self.password = [self someRandomPasswordGenerator];
}

- (void)test_registration {
    // register with MyTestCase.email, MyTestCase.password
}

- (void)test_signup() {
    // signup with MyTestCase.email, MyTestCase.password
}
```

Note, however, as other have said, that it's not guaranteed that the registration test will run before the signup one, as Xcode has it's own logic. Currently it picks up tests in alphabetical order, however that might change, and parallelization is another aspect that might give you headaches.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using a segue:

```html
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC: nameofdestinationVC = segue.destination as! nameofdestinationVC
        destinationVC.string = string var in other VC!
        
    }
```